# Lua To Unix Executable File?

Tags: macos, unix, lua, executable

Okay, so I was wondering if I could convert a .lua script to a Unix Executable with Mac OS X. Could that be possible? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: executable how? `chmod +x`? Add a shebang line?

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#7):

> Lua scripts can be made into executable programs by using `chmod +x` and the `#!` form, as in

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/lua
```

> The location of the Lua interpreter may be different in your machine. If lua is in your `PATH` then a more portable solution is

```
 #!/usr/bin/env lua
```

Try also [srlua](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#srlua) for instance.  It's a tool for building self-running Lua programs.